# (apt-get) Pipe error

Tags: package-management, thirdpartyapps

The last thing I have installed was lazarus and now when I try to install anything with apt I get a error. Lazarus compiles just fine without any errors. Example.

```
$ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
[sudo] password for user:                 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ffmpeg : Depends: libavdevice-ffmpeg56 (>= 7:2.6) but it is not going to be installed
 fp-utils-3.0.0 : Depends: fpc-source-3.0.0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I run `sudo apt-get -f install`

```
~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0
  libappstream3 libatkmm-1.6-1v5 libcairomm-1.0-1v5 libglibmm-2.4-1v5 libido3-0.1-0
  libpangomm-1.4-1v5 libsigc++-2.0-0v5 libvala-0.32-0 sbsigntool
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fpc-source-3.0.0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fpc-source-3.0.0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
98 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/15.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 166 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 223502 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../fpc-source-3.0.0_3.0.0+dfsg-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking fpc-source-3.0.0 (3.0.0+dfsg-2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/fpc-source-3.0.0_3.0.0+dfsg-2_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/fpcsrc/3.0.0/rtl/android/jvm/java_sys_android.inc', which is also in package fpc-src 3.0.0
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/fpc-source-3.0.0_3.0.0+dfsg-2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

[EDIT]: No matter what I use apt for I still get the same error. Even after trying to remove the package causing the issue.

```
~$ sudo apt remove fpc-src
[sudo] password for user:                 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fp-utils-3.0.0 : Depends: fpc-source-3.0.0 but it is not going to be installed
 lazarus-project : Depends: fpc-src (>= 3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                            fpc-source (>= 3.0.0)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying to fix this countless of times I found a solution.

First I ran

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

then

`sudo apt-get install -f` (Too see what package gives the problem)

After I saw the problem was still there I edited it manually.

I Located the corrupt package, and removed the whole block of information about it and saved the file.

```
sudo -i nano /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

After I removed the broken package I ran `sudo apt-get install -f` and it fixed apt-get

Answer (score 0):

You will have to remove the `fpc-src`package first (`sudo apt remove fpc-src`), and run `apt-get install -f` after (and reinstall the new packages eventually).

Comment: No matter what I use it still gives me the same error. I basically can't use apt